# Iterator to replace if/else Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have the following code lines. I need to check each button (there are 4: a,b,c,d) and compare if the answer is right. If it is, I say that the button set its color to green.

But I need to reduce this code, with a iterator or something like that, because if increase the quantity of buttons will be more complicated.

```
if(currentQuestion.getOptA().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))
{
    buttonA.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
} else if(currentQuestion.getOptB().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))
{
    buttonB.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
} else if(currentQuestion.getOptC().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))
{
    buttonC.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
} else if(currentQuestion.getOptD().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))
{
    buttonD.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
}
```

Comment: Have a look at arrays and loops.

Comment: use switch case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through a view's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809834/how-to-iterate-through-a-views-elements)

Comment: I do not wanna write a long answer but I think you can reduce code and complexity by using switch for each button and implement your background there this way it will savethe remaining if checks. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object possibleAnswers [] = {currentQuestion.getOptA(), currentQuestion.getOptB(), currentQuestion.getOptC(), currentQuestion.getOptD()};
Button buttons [] = {buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD};

for (int i = 0; i < possibleAnswers.lenght; i++) {
    if (currentQuestion.getAnswer().equals(possibleAnswers[i]) {
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also create an method in Question class to return the array of choices... Something like:

```
public Object [] getPossibleAnswers() {
    return new Object[] {currentQuestion.getOptA(), currentQuestion.getOptB(), currentQuestion.getOptC(), currentQuestion.getOptD()};
}
```

And then,

```
Object possibleAnswers [] = currentQuestion.getPossibleAnswers();
```

**NOTE**

I used `Object` because I don't know your class's name.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is:

1) get the `count` of the buttons

2) make an `array` and put inside the dynamic portion of the var you want to check e.g. `a,b,c,d`

3) use a `for` to iterate `from 0 to count of buttons`

4) compare each time the name by concatenating the static portion of the name plus the dynamic portion of the array e.g. getOpt is the static and the a, b c, d is the dynamic portion of the name

So, with this "technique" you will be able to scale your checks with zero effort just by adding a new value to the `array` with `a,b,c,d`

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be checking one thing and setting another (which correspond to each other), you should go for a `HashMap`.

You would then iterate over the map (which stores a key and value combo) and if the key matches the right answer, then you use the value to set the background colour.

```
public HashMap<String, JButton> getQuestionAndAnswers() {
     HashMap<String, JButton> result = new HashMap<>();
     result.put(currentQuestion.getOptA(), buttonA);
     ....
}
```

And then you could use it like so:

```
HashMap<String, JButton> qaa = getQuestionAndAnswers();
foreach(String key in qaa) {
     if(key.equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()) {            qaa.get(key).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
     break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the following way I suggest that you should use `RadioGroup` and also use a selector for each `radioButton` and set unchecked and checked states for that.

you most create a drawable shape like this:

```
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/lightGreen"
      />


        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/yourOffColor"
            />
    </shape>

</item>
```

and use this in java when the ans in true set her button checked like this:
:

```
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int radioID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int ansID= 2; //replace your id

            radioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioID);

            if (radioID == ansID){
            radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }}
    });
```

this is a way that i using in my app perhaps useful for you