# Get the text of a dynamically created textfield in android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

So I'm trying to figure out how I would get the text from a dynamically created EditText field.
This is the code for the dynamic Text fields

```
private fun AddToDoItem() {
  val EditText = EditText(this)
  EditText.gravity = Gravity.TOP
  EditText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
  EditText.tag = "ExtraField" + i
  LinearLayout?.addView(EditText)
  i++
}
```

And this is the code where I want to get the Textfields text

```
    Finish.setOnClickListener {
        var x = 0
        val userId = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
        val mcDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        mcDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).child(ToDoName.text.toString()).push()

        while (x < i) {
            val currentUserDb = mDatabaseReference!!.child(userId).child(ToDoName.text.toString())
            currentUserDb.child(i.toString()).setValue("ExtraField" + x.text) //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SET THE TEXT
            x++
            Toast.makeText(this, "Finished.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Where its commented like "//HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SET THE TEXT" is where I want the .text string.

(It's in the while loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

You are adding the `EditText`'s to a `LinearLayout` therefore you can iterate over its children - as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809834/how-to-iterate-through-a-views-elements) and therefore replacing the while loop.

The second way would be to add the `EditText`'s to a `List<EditText>` and iterate over it, replacing the while loop.

The first solution would probably be cleaner, but both of them work in a very similar fashion.

Hope this helps you!